# Proper way to response nothing to ajax request on Spring

Tags: spring

I'm sending AJAX request to make simple CRUD happens on my project, asynchronously

I don't need any response from server, I just need to insert, update or delete data on database.

I also learned there must be a response to a request, so I tried some ways to fake it, but all of them didn't feel right.

1. return meaningless value

Just return any value like boolean or empty String, and not using it

```java
@PostMapping("/whatever")
public @ResponseBody boolean something() {
  doSomething();
  return true;
}
```

2. return something, but not using it

Almost same as 1, since I'm not using it

```java
@PostMapping("/whatever")
public @ResponseBody MyObject something() {
  doSomething();
  return new MyObject();
}
```

3. doesn't care about response, just get errors and don't mind it

Use catch or always with ajax request, a lot of errors on console, it really doesn't feel right

```java
@PostMapping("/whatever")
public void something() {
  doSomething();
}
```

```java
@PostMapping("/whatever")
public String something() {
  doSomething();
  return "/page/url";
}
```

All of them works as I want, but it makes me thinking there could be a better way to write a code when I don't need any response.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Usually when you do an insert you need some sort of id generated and returned

Comment: There will be a response, because that's how HTTP works.  What you put in that response is up to you and can be a simple HTTP 200 OK (however you provide that in Spring)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)` annotation to the controller route and then you do not need to return anything. Your prototype will be "public void doSomething()".

We use this for delete calls.